# C# Setting Print Region for envelope

Tags: c#, printing

I'm trying to do a very simple operation:

1. Get list of local printers, let user select (Got this)
2. Select Envelope tray for manual feed
3. Print client Address to specific envelope size (4 1/8 x 9 1/2 / 03982) on manual envelope feed printer.

I have no experience with System.Drawing.Printing class so pardon my ignorance on the topic.

I'm fooling around with the code I found below, I've been playing around with the:`Rectangle(20, 20, 200, etc.));` but haven't been able to figure out how to subtract it to the appropriate margin or get the envelope tray.

[image: Rectangle Class]

### EDIT - Working Code (Thanks to icemanind for pointing me in the right direction.

```
   //Load
   foreach (String printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters) {
          printersList.Items.Add(printer.ToString());
    }

    private void btPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var pd = new PrintDocument();
            //Set PrinterName as the selected printer in the printers list
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printersList.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(200, 200, 200, 200);
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = 6;
            pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
            pd.Print();
    }

    public void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
            //Get Address From Database or Pass In
            var vnId = Lnq.Orders.Where(a => a.ID == OrdId).Select(a => a.fk_ClientAttID).FirstOrDefault();
            var a = Lnq.Clients.Where(a => a.ID == vnId).Select(a => new {a.Name, a.Addy1, a.City, a.State, a.Zip});
            foreach (var v in e)
            {
                var g = ev.Graphics;
                var font = new Font("Arial", 12);
                var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                g.DrawString(a.Name + "\n" + a.Addy1  + "\n" + a.City + ", " 
                             + a.State + " " + a.Zip, font, brush,
                             new Rectangle(500, 400, 650, 650));
            }
    }
```

Comment: Try PrinterSettings.PaperSizes property

Comment: Use the PageSetupDialog class to make it interactive and intuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# has a [PaperSourceKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersourcekind(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration that it defines for various printing medias. One of these is `ManualFeed` which is described as `Manually fed envelope`. You should be able to set the [RawKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersource.rawkind(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `6`, which is the `ManualFeed` value.

Once you set that, you shouldn't have to worry about scaling it down to fit. It should automatically do that.